# Is there a way to control casper's console output?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, casperjs

Just want to know if it's possible to force casperjs to only output failed tests to the console.
Has anyone tried to do that?

Thank you

Comment: What I have now is that casperjs writes PASS + 'some message' in the console for every assertion that passes in unit tests. I need to know the way how to make casperjs to output only FAIL message (for some assertion that failed) in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running the CasperJS test environment, you can add the [`--concise` option](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#options) when you run CasperJS:

```
casperjs test --concise yourTest.js
```

This hides all assertion logs, but doesn't hide the additional info of FAILs:

```
Test file: test20_only_show_fail.js
#    type: assert
#    file: test20_only_show_fail.js:8
#    code: test.assert(false, "false");
#    subject: false
#    type: assert
#    file: test20_only_show_fail.js:13
#    code: test.assert(false, "false");
#    subject: false
FAIL 3 tests executed in 0.027s, 1 passed, 2 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

But now you can't distinguish them easily. You can add an event listener to the front of your test file and let it print something useful:

```
casper.test.on("fail", function(failure) {
    this.casper.echo("FAIL " + failure.message);
});
```

This produces the FAIL lines that come after the additional information:

```
Test file: test20_only_show_fail.js
#    type: assert
#    file: test20_only_show_fail.js:7
#    code: test.assert(false, "false");
#    subject: false
FAIL false
#    type: assert
#    file: test20_only_show_fail.js:12
#    code: test.assert(false, "false");
#    subject: false
FAIL false
FAIL 3 tests executed in 0.028s, 1 passed, 2 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

This is the test file (test20_only_show_fail.js) for reference:

```
casper.test.on("fail", function(failure) {
    this.casper.echo("FAIL " + failure.message);
});

casper.test.begin('fail test', function(test) {
    test.assert(true, "true");
    test.assert(false, "false");
    test.assert(true, "true (2)");
});

casper.test.begin('error test', function(test) {
    test.assert(false, "false");
});
```